# django no puedo enviar correo por shell

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electrónico desde shell usando Django. me muestra un error de atributo, por favor encuentre aquí el código1

-Configuración del archivo `setting.py`, abajo de todo pongo los siguientes parámetros:

```
MAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER="micorreo@gmail.com" <----email desde donde voy a mandar los mails
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="123456"


>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('pruebba de asuento', 'este seria el mensaje','micorreo@gmail.com', ['barbydecarasa@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

y me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darksun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    return getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp' has no attribute 'EmailBackEnd'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\darksun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 55, in send_mail
    fail_silently=fail_silently,
  File "C:\Users\darksun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "C:\Users\darksun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 24, in import_string
    ) from err
ImportError: Module "django.core.mail.backends.smtp" does not define a "EmailBackEnd" attribute/class
```

No estoy muy seguro de por qué aparece este error, he cambiado la configuración de seguridad en mi correo electrónico. y he seguido los pasos de los tutoriales y no estoy seguro de que mi error sea.

Answer (score 1):

Has guardado cambios de :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
```

Pone una "E" mayuscula como si estuviera mal escrito

```
has no attribute 'EmailBackEnd'
```

debes poner "EmailBackend" y guardar los cambios

Comment: esta asi amigo fijese ahi arriba donde puse el codigo  MAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

Comment: Ya lo sé. Prueba a poner en la variable EMAIL_BACKEND. Te falta una "E" veo diferente.     EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'